# PHP POST does not work (I'm getting GET instead)

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I have a simple web form which does not work anymore. After submitting via the POST method it turns to GET (and clears). The simplified version of the form:

`<form method="POST" action="index.html">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with redirecting from **non-www** to **www** (rewrite rule in .htaccess). The POST data has been cutted by the redirect . Putting just "index.html" into the action attribute of the form tag led to non-www version, then was redirected to www version but without POST data attached.

I have changed the action attribute of the form tag and the form works now as expected.

`<form method="POST" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
        ...
</form>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want data to be sent to the index.html and you are on the same page use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

else, use `action="index.php" method="post"`